# Why say "Make this a comment" for <50 reputation users?

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation

**Disclaimer:** I wrote this in (hopefully) the form of a discussion question, but note it is going to be biased towards my opinion.

I see this situation almost **every single day** mostly in the Low Quality Post review.  A user who has <50 rep leaves an answer that *should be a comment* and another user >50 rep leaves a comment on the post something along the lines of:

> Please make this a comment on the question, it is not really an answer.

As I said, I mostly see this while reviewing Low Quality Post's and I **fully agree** that most of the answers I see there *would be better off as comments* (or burned with fire).  However I personally feel very strongly that it is **NOT** helpful to the situation or the OP of the answer if you tell them to "make this a comment" when they do not have the privilege yet.

When I come along and see this I usually leave an additional comment saying something along the lines of:

> @commenter While I agree this answer should be turned into a comment or removed all together, this user has <50 reputation so it does not help to tell them to make this a comment when they do not have the privileges yet.

(Lately I have been seeing this more an more, and I have started to get a little frustrated and have been neglecting the "While I agree.." part, and just tell them [this user has <50 rep...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893760/spring-cannot-find-bean-xml-configuration-file-when-it-does-exist/30397235#comment48886234_30397235))  Which is why I felt I needed to start a meta discussion.

Since I keep seeing this happen, and even sometimes from high(ish, >10k?) reputation users, I need to ask is it actually helpful to tell <50 reputation users to explicitly "Make this a comment"?  Is there some "official" course of action that I have neglected to find (besides hitting the <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> button)?

Just to note what I usually do, is just direct the OP to:
[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) instead of telling them to "make this a comment".  Is this appropriate?

Comment: Kinda ranty.  How is the commenter supposed to know when the poster gets 50 rep?  It might not take more than an hour or so.

Comment: @HansPassant what do you mean? The commenter can see at the time of posting it that the author doesn't have enough rep. Or maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: I'm totally guilty of this, thanks for bringing it up.  I'll be sure to leave more helpful comments next time.

Comment: @code - it just isn't relevant, what matters is when the poster acts on the comment.  If it takes him a day to get 5 votes, no problem.  If it takes him a week, not great.  If it takes him a month, well, that's not the commenter's problem is it?

Comment: @HansPassant So if I understand correctly, you are saying it is helpful then to leave that sort of comment for when the OP does achieve the proper rep so they can go back and see the comment, and turn their answer into a comment?

Comment: Sure.  And if that doesn't happen for some reason (user abandons site or just can't ever get any votes) then the post can be flagged for moderator attention.  They have a single button click available to turn a post into a comment.

Comment: If you are in the Low Quality Review, chances that *anyone* will see a comment before the item is deleted is small. I comment and don't click "delete" to give a better chance, but I suspect it is not much longer before the answer-as-a-comment is removed. So OP is left wondering "what happened there?" and doesn't get to learn anything.

Comment: @HansPassant these posts get picked up pretty quickly, and killed pretty quickly. Perhaps a "turn post to comment" option in Low Quality may be useful?

Comment: @Bill, OP will see the comment on their deleted answer (it is still viewable to them), and learn that they should not really Post non-answers.

Comment: @JonasCz Ah. Didn't know that. I will return to using the Delete after my comment.

Comment: @BillWoodger: That option doesn't exist for non-mods because it will be severely overused by reviewers trying to be "nice". Delete it, and iff you think it brings up a point *you* want to ask about, add a comment where appropriate *on your own behalf*.

Comment: @Deduplicator Reference for that? I can't just up and delete posts, but I get the delete button there. Why not "convert to comment" if enough people clicked it in the same way?

Comment: @Deduplicator, Has it ever been tried ? I don't see how it would be so bad, often those answers would actually be useful as comments, and it saves others from tyPing out the same thing.

Comment: @Bill: As shog9 puts it, because too many crappy (non-)answers will be turned into equally crappy comments (That is, borderline answer to crappy comment, crappy answer to crappy comment, and the like). Also, they might need fixups as those have different markdown. Also, convert into comment *on which post*?

Comment: See rationale on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86121/can-we-make-convert-to-a-comment-a-10k-20k-user-tool

Comment: @Deduplicator Crappy answers do not necessarily result in crappy comments, especially if it were made available only to hig-rep (5k +) users. It could be made to work in such a way that a certain amount of clicks on "convert to comment" are necessary. Usually, they should be comments on the question, but the reviewers are there to click the buton, and if it does not belong on the question, they wont click the button (hopefully). Markdown shouldn't be a problem. From your link, backdoor commenting can probably be avoided some way also.

Comment: @JonasCz: How would you select the target post? How would you ensure the non-answer is not mis-representing the original author? And anyway, high-rep users should not be proxies. Also, when a post is converted, its former comments will probably need severe pruning, which needs mod priviliges.

Comment: @Deduplicator I can't find (search-engineing) shog9's text. The link is four years old. We have the Delete, why would we use the Convert over the Delete where the Delete was more appropriate? If in doubt, make sure the Convert is to the right of Delete, so it would be more mouse-time-consuming.

Comment: @BillWoodger The problem is too many people are scared of deleting crap, and would rather try and save the crap than just get rid of it, when given the choice.  As has been said, if you *really* think the content of the post is *that* valuable, you can post it yourself as a comment.  The *vast* majority of these types of answers should just be deleted, and trying to save those that might be useful would cause more problems than it'd solve.

Comment: A few months ago when I still had less than 50 rep, I was able to post comments by first making a short answer, then before it was posted, I had an automatic message telling me something like "Are you sure you don't want to post it as a comment instead ?". Back then, I though it was a feature and did it a few times. (I even got the [commentator](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/31/commentator?userid=3702797) badge before [I had the 50 rep needed](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=5)). Has this bug/feature been removed since then ?

Comment: Now you people understand why poor reviews are such a problem.

Comment: If these users bothered to post decent answer instead of some crappy comment, then they'd have 50 rep in no time at all.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, it's not particularly helpful if the answerer doesn't have the required rep. If you don't address the fact that you understand that they can't leave a comment then you usually get flack from the author saying something like, "I know it's a comment but I don't have the required rep so I left it as an answer so I could help". Or something along those lines which creates more "noise" and can result in poor attitudes between the users.

### The good people at SE have given us a solution

There is an [auto comment](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) that addresses this particular situation (note: requires [an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoreviewcomments/bcfoamnigomkoaaiceppbbdlembpeejc?hl=en-US))

[image]

[image]

### How it can be handled

I've saved the same thing for posting minus the "I'm flagging this post for deletion" because I think it may sound a little harsh for new community members.

However, if I'm in this situation then I do something similar usually and ping the commentor to tell them that the OP **can't** comment. Not much else you can do there.

### Not much we can do about people leaving subpar comments

As far as the users leaving those comments, I'm not sure what you expect to be done about it. Yes, they should realize the user can't post a comment and address it a little more properly but...whatchya gonna do 'bout that?

Comment: Where is that auto comment found?  I didn't even know that existed.

Comment: I don't see that in the list of options in LQp, where is it ?

Comment: Ah are you referring to http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Comment: @chancea yep, sorry added to the post

Comment: @JonasCz see the updated answer and comments

Comment: Oh. I use that, never thought of using it in LQp though.

Comment: @codeMagic Thank you for this, I didn't know this extension existed and I am glad to see that there is a somewhat "official" response I can give users in this situation.  I will wait a bit to see if anyone else answers but most likely will accept this.

Comment: I will admit that I am guilty of this.  I will use your suggestions to make my review efforts better.

Comment: I doubt "For the moment, I'm your proxy" is a good idea in general.

Comment: @Deduplicator What's wrong with it if you agree with the comment (or even if you don't)? If I do this, I use a disclaimer that it came from that person. If I don't I don't comment and leave that part out of the auto comment. I've never had issues doing it in the past. That's usually the end of it.

Comment: Here's the thing. One of the review queues gives you a similar auto comment that changes depending on whether the user has enough rep to comment, for free. But only one of them. The rest don't. Why?

Comment: @BoltClock Easy: it's the Low Quality Queue. And the rest don't have that comment, because reviewers there do not vote to delete or recommend deletion; they just flag.

Comment: @BoltClock maybe because I haven't had any coffee yet or I'm just not following, but I don't understand what you're getting at. The LQ doesn't seem to change. I tried with a user who had 1 rep and one who had 200+ and they were the same options. What am I missing here? As for the why, I would guess because. I would have guess the Late Answers but I couldn't test as there were no reviews.

Comment: Why say "The good people at SE have given us a solution", if this requires an extension that wasn't authored by the staff?

Answer (score 12):

Earning 50 reputation isn't difficult.  25 approved edits, 3 1/3 accepted answers, 5 answer upvotes, 10 question upvotes, or a linear combination of same.

"This should be a comment" does mean for someone less than 50 reputation "you have to earn enough reputation to comment first".  And yes, this is a barrier to entry.

In short, go earn 50 reputation, then post your stuff as a comment.  If you just post comments as answers, you'll go backwards towards the 50 reputation requirement.

Comment: The first 50 rep I earned was the most difficult 50 rep I earned. Always remember that low-rep people and lurkers are under-represented on meta and so we don't get an accurate impression of what obstacles beginners have.

Comment: I remember when I was down there, and I wouldn't even think about editing posts. I has seen way to many bashful comments that I was scared to take a wrong step and get crushed if I edited something wrong. Not everyone has been lurking around for months and knows all the rules, so when someone decides to register he does not necessarily know how to behave according to community rules and might refrain himself from getting "easy" reputation. (That's pure speculation by the way).

Comment: Why do so many people on Meta (who know the system!) state that earning 50 rep isn't that hard? If you're new to the site (a few days), it can be very difficult to get into the culture of asking and answering questions.

Comment: I answered two questions on my first day.  By the next day, one had earned me 55 rep, the other 60.  [they where not great](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13071861/1774667), but [not horrible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13092671/1774667) answers.  My next 3-4 answers averaged over 30 points each.  So between 1 and 2 answers was enough to break 50 in my experience.  If you understand the subject you are answering, it isn't that hard.  If you don't understand the subject, ask questions instead of commenting/answering.

Comment: @Yakk: You got lucky. Understanding the subject is not enough, you also have to race to answer the question before everybody else. As a beginner to SO, you don't realise what niche you can fill and so you spend a lot of time trying to earn rep in crowded areas.

Comment: @Flimm I answered 23 minutes after the questions where asked, and 6 minutes after another answer in one case.  In the other case, I answered within 2 minutes of the question being posted, and another answer was accepted (but had fewer upvotes).  I did search for and answer the newest C++ questions feed, if you call that luck?  I am posting on the 9th most popular tag (it was 7th or 8th when I started here), so not a niche.  The only remaining variable would be claiming that today it is much harder than 2-3 years ago.

Comment: Once bitten, twice shy. I had some unpleasant responses to a few initial attempts, deleted my user entirely... came back months later, tried again slowly. Reticent to do anything 'wrong' again. Strangely, I just got +100 on all (8) sites I had registered on, seemingly for doing nothing. Went from 31 to 131 on this site for no reason. Felt very nice though! "Comment Everywhere" Indeed! I do.

Comment: @nocomprende The first time you pass 200 rep on **any** SE site, *and* have accounts on two SE sites, you earn a free +100 on every site (including the one you passed 200 on).  [association bonus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147951/association-bonus-100)

Comment: @Yakk: Pass 200, Collect *GO!* ha ha. But I was commenting on how I was stuck at 31 for a long time, then, for no significant reason, was vaulted over 100...? Arbitrary to me. I always used to puzzle why SO MANY people have 101 rep.

Comment: @nocomprende Your buddist account broke 200, so your SO account got +100.